# No redirection to the app with Spring Boot + OAuth2 + Gitlab authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gitlab, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to add authentication layer to my app. It should use OAuth2 provided by our local Gitlab.

I have registered the app on Gitlab, so I get the `security.oauth2.client.clientId` and `security.oauth2.client.clientSecret` from there. I have set the Redirect URI to `http://localhost:8080/index.html`.

Now for the Spring application.properties, the OAuth2 part looks like this:

```
security.oauth2.client.clientId=SOME_ID
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret=SOME_SECRET
security.oauth2.client.accessToken=https://gitlab.ourserver.com/oauth/access_token
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri=https://gitlab.ourserver.com/users/sign_in
security.oauth2.client.tokenName=oauth_token
security.oauth2.client.authenticationScheme=query
security.oauth2.client.clientAuthenticationScheme=form

security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri=userInfoUri: https://gitlab.ourserver.com/api/v4/user
```

The main application class is annotated with:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class GeneratorApplication
```

That is all for the configuration.

When I go to http://localhost:8080/index.html it is redirecting to the Gitlab login page, but after logging in it stays on the gitlab page...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried redirect-uri ?

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-1.redirect-uri-template
```

Please check the official spring security [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html)